# Skip item with more columns when creating Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists:

```
list = [
  ['Row 1','Value 1'],
  ['Row 2', 'Value 2'],
  ['Row 3', 'Value 3', 'Value 4']
]
```

And I have a list for dataframe header:

```
header_list = ['RowID', 'Value']
```

If I create the DataFrame using `df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns = header_list)`, then `python` will through me an error says Row3 has more than 2 columns, which is inconsistent with the header_list.

So how can I skip Row 3 when creating the `DataFrame`. And how to achieve this with "in-place" calculation, which means NOT creating a new list which loops through the original list and append the item with `length=2`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First change variable `list` to `L`, because `list` is python code reserved word.

Then for filter use list comprehension:

```
L = [['Row 1','Value 1'], ['Row 2', 'Value 2'], ['Row 3', 'Value 3', 'Value 4']]

#for omit all rows != 2
df = pd.DataFrame([x  for x in L if len(x) == 2], columns = header_list)
print (df)
   RowID    Value
0  Row 1  Value 1
1  Row 2  Value 2
```

---

```
#filter last 2 values if len != 2
df = pd.DataFrame([x if len(x) == 2 else x[-2:] for x in L], columns = header_list)
print (df)
     RowID    Value
0    Row 1  Value 1
1    Row 2  Value 2
2  Value 3  Value 4
```

Or:

```
#filter first 2 values if len != 2
df = pd.DataFrame([x if len(x) == 2 else x[:2] for x in L], columns = header_list)
print (df)
   RowID    Value
0  Row 1  Value 1
1  Row 2  Value 2
2  Row 3  Value 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
list1 = [['Row 1','Value 1'], ['Row 2', 'Value 2'], ['Row 3', 'Value 3']]
dff = pd.DataFrame(list1)
dff = dff[[x for x in range(len(header_list))]]
dff.columns = header_list
```